# Problem extracting specific transcript sequences from genome

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm working on Linux in R to get specific transcript sequences from the genome. I am able to import the genome, extract transcripts annotations (tx), and get transcript sequences (tx_seq). I am also able to import genomic annotations for the transcripts I'm interested in as GRanges (uorf_annotations) and convert them transcript coordinates (uorf_tx_annotations).

The libraries I have loaded are

```
#BiocManager::install(version="3.9")
#BiocManager::install("BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19")
#BiocManager::install("S4Vectors")
#BiocManager::install(c("GenomicFeatures", "Biostrings", "GenomicRanges"))
library(broom)
library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19)
library(Biostrings)
library(GenomicRanges)
library(GenomicFeatures)
library(rtracklayer)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyranges)
options(scipen=999)
```

The chunk of code that works is

```
uorf_tx_annotations <- mapToTranscripts(uorf_annotations, tx) %>%
  print()
```

I get stuck when I try and get the transcript sequences from uorf_tx_annotations. The code I am using for this step is

```
uorf_transcript_seq <- extractTranscriptSeqs(genome, uorf_tx_annotations) %>%
  print()
```

and the error I am getting is "Error in extractTranscriptSeqs(genome, uorf_tx_annotations) : failed to extract the exon ranges from 'transcripts' with exonsBy(transcripts, by="tx", ...)"

I use extractTranscriptSeqs earlier on to get tx_seq, so I'm not sure what's wrong here. I thought that everything I needed was in GRanges, but in case uorf_annotations wasn't in the GRanges I tried (inspired from documentation at https://rdrr.io/bioc/GenomicFeatures/man/extractTranscriptSeqs.html)

```
uorf_tx_annotations <- mapToTranscripts(uorf_annotations, tx) %>%
  exonsBy(by = "tx") %>%
  print()
```

but this just introduces a new error: "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘exonsBy’ for signature ‘"GRanges"’"

Comment: I would not expect sequences to be in annotations.  Can you explain why you think they would?. ALSO ... put in `library()` calls for all needed packages. The page you linked to has a complete example. You need to follow that example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include all of my code. The libraries I have called are broom, BSgenome.Hsapiens.hg19, Biostrings, GenomicRanges, GenomicFeatures, rtracklayer, tidyverse, and plyranges if that's what you meant I'm confused about the library() code you suggested. I don't expect sequences to be within annotations but I thought that annotations were holding the start and end coordinates that would yield sequences when called to a reference.

Comment: In R `library()` calls are used to load "packages".

Comment: does my edit that shows which libraries I used address your comment?

Comment: Still no complete example. I am executing the update to Bioc 3.9 and it is a huge update. If either that cited page or the _packages_ that have your suggested functions have [MCVE]s then you should use those examples tosupply code that builds  objects that are sufficiently similar to your data-objects, `genome`, `uorf_annotations`, and  `tx`.

Comment: It did and I spent a good hour or two updating my Bioc packages, but the question still doesn’t have enough information to tell what the problem is. No [MCVE]. No clear descriptions of the object structures.